# mysql join where in

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv, where-clause

Table 1:

```
id    name         value_ids    
1     extras       5,6 
2     brand        7
```

Table 2:

```
id  value
5   extra1  
6   extra2  
7   brand1
```

My Question is, how to query the tables to get smth like that:

1.

```
name     value
extras   extra1,extra2
brand    brand1
```

or

2.

```
name     value
extras   extra1
extras   extra2
brand    brand1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the second resultset with `find_in_set()`:

```
select t1.name, t2.value
from t1
inner join t2 on find_in_set(t2.id, t1.value_ids)
```

A far better alternative would be to fix your data model. You should not be storing multiple values (numbers !) in a single column. Instead, you should have a separate table to represent the many-to-many relationship between the tables, with each tuple of ids stored in a separate row.

Recommended reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.value
   FROM table_1 t1
   INNER JOIN table_2 t2 ON find_in_set(t2.id , t1.value_ids);
```